# Finding similar method filterContext.ActionParameters in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

ActionExecutingContext.ActionParameters was used in ASP.NET MVC5 find a similar method in ASP.NET Core. [link for reference of ActionParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext.actionparameters?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

I want to set action-method parameters in ActionFilterAttribute in ASP.NET Core which I should able to read in Action Method.

Below code snippet, I am trying to find out ways to set action-method parameters

**Want to Set action-method parameters in ActionFilterAttribute which are retrieved from Querystring**

```
public class DecryptQueryStringParameterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var dataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create("Frapper.Web");
        var protector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("Frapper.Web.QueryStrings");

        Dictionary<string, object> decryptedParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["q"].ToString() != null)
        {
            string decrptedString = protector.Unprotect(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["q"].ToString());
            string[] getRandom = decrptedString.Split('[');

            var format = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
            var dateCheck = Convert.ToDateTime(getRandom[2], format);

            TimeSpan diff = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now, format) - dateCheck;

            /* For Development it is been commented */
            //if (diff.Minutes > 30)
            //{
            //    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Error", controller = "Error" }));
           // filterContext.ActionDescriptor.Parameters.Add();
            //}

            string[] paramsArrs = getRandom[1].Split('?');

            for (int i = 0; i < paramsArrs.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] paramArr = paramsArrs[i].Split('=');
                decryptedParameters.Add(paramArr[0], Convert.ToString(paramArr[1]));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < decryptedParameters.Count; i++)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Items.Add(decryptedParameters.Keys.ElementAt(i), decryptedParameters.Values.ElementAt(i));
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    }
}
```

**Reading Values**

```
  [ServiceFilter(typeof(DecryptQueryStringParameterAttribute))]
    public ActionResult CustomerEdit(string AppId)
    {
        return PartialView("_CustomerPartialView");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

ActionArguments are available in ASP.NET Core which is similar to ActionParameters which was used ASP.NET MVC 5. Using this I am able to set Values to Action Parameters.

**ASP.NET MVC 5**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < decryptedParameters.Count; i++)
 {
      filterContext.ActionParameters[decryptedParameters.Keys.ElementAt(i)] = decryptedParameters.Values.ElementAt(i);
 }
```

**ASP.NET Core**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < decryptedParameters.Count; i++)
 {
     filterContext.ActionArguments[decryptedParameters.Keys.ElementAt(i)] = decryptedParameters.Values.ElementAt(i);
 }
```